# date_format not validating in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I am using this validation for dates:

```
'fiscal_end' => 'required|date_format:dd/mm/yyyy'
```

Doing:

```
print_r(Input::all());
die();
```

I get:

```
[fiscal_end] => 25/01/2017
```

I don't understand what's wrong here that generates the error: Date needs to be in proper format dd/mm/yyyy.

I am using Laravel 5.3 and datefield on form is actually Bootstrap Datepicker field.

Comment: check which format in bootstrap datepicker?

Comment: add this to your jquery code $('#Id').datepicker({ format: 'dd/mm/yyyy' });

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are doing with wrong format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Change your format as `d/m/Y`

Comment: Thank you, I was suspecting that :)